# Xcode failing on running app on physical device

Tags: xcode, xcode11, swift5, watchos-6

When I'm trying to run apple watch standalone app on physical device its throwing this error:

Error:

```
Details

Unable to install "TinyRage WatchKit App"
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620394
--
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.
Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit
Code: -402620394
Failure Reason: The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file are invalid, not permitted, or do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487927;
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e6e16e7 DTDKCreateNSError + 109
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e6e1de9 DTDK_AMDErrorToNSError + 792
    2   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e72156a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 164
    3   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000103851156 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 73
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011e721301 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1589
    5   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000011e5baa25 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.352 + 4523
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001039823ba __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    7   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000103983a92 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 809
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7306d5f8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7306e63d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff730748e0 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 602
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff73075396 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 385
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff7307d6ed _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff732ae611 _pthread_wqthread + 421
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff732ae3fd start_wqthread + 13
);
}
--
```

However with another app everything works correctly without any issues.